# Openshift origin 3.11 scaleup.yaml fails on task "Approve node certificates when bootstrapping"

Tags: linux, certificate, kubernetes

I am using OpenShift Origin 3.11 with 3 master, 3 infra and 6 worker nodes. I've tried to scale up the 7th worker node and the scaleup playbook fails at task 
 **`Approve node certificates when bootstrapping`**

It retries 30 times for the CSR to be signed and then the playbook ends with one failed task for one of the master. The playbook suggests that I use `join.yaml` next time to add this 7th server.

```bash
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (30 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (29 retries left).
...
FAILED - RETRYING: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping (1 retries left).
```

I checked the CSR via `oc get csr` and it was `Approved,Issued`.  I checked the nodes state via `oc get nodes` and it was ready.  While the pods can be scaled on the node, the only problem that I face with this 7th node is I can't see the logs for the pod using `oc logs ovs-rzw43`, receiving the following error:

```bash
Error from server: Get https://worker07-hostname:10250/containerLogs/openshift-sdn/ovs-rzw43/openvswitch: **net/http: TLS handshake timeout**
```

When I increased the verbosity, I see the following command succeeds

```bash
curl GET -H "Authorization: Bearer nBCX0jVCwuoDiZI13-jMafu3BoW6VjOgCf1TTnhH"  https://master.mycloud.com:8443/api/v1/namespaces/openshift-sdn/pods/ovs-rzw43
```

While this command fails (only difference is the `/log` at the end):

```bash
curl GET -H "Authorization: Bearer nBCX0jVCwuoDiZI13-jMafu3BoW6VjOgCf1TTnhH"  https://master.mycloud.com:8443/api/v1/namespaces/openshift-sdn/pods/ovs-rzw43/log
```

I found a lot of threads on the internet, but no resolution, two of which are:

- [Failure when adding node: Approve node certificates when bootstrapping](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=users@lists.openshift.redhat.com&q=subject:%22Re%5C%3A%20Failure%20when%20adding%20node%20%5C-%20Approve%20node%20certificates%20when%09bootstrapping%22&o=newest&f=1)
- [Bug 1622945: Installation stuck at TASK [Approve node certificates when bootstrapping]](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1622945)

Comment: Please make use of the correct markdown via the markdown formatting bar.  `Monospaced code` should be placed within backticks or a code box; [weblinks](https://please-use-proper.markdown) should be linked text, not the URL; Bullteted or numbered lists help organize information under relevant sentences/paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

Edit the /etc/origin/master/master.env file to add the new nodes in the no_proxy parameter, and restart the master api and controllers on all master nodes.